# MLB record for consecutive years with an identical batting average (single player)

Tags: baseball, statistics

Khris Davis has had the same batting average for four consecutive years. Have other batters with 100 or more plate appearances in each year done this?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Reading the article, there is only one other player who managed to have the same batting average for 3 consecutive years. **Mookie Wilson, with .276 from 1983 to 1985.

[The Most Consistent Hitter In Baseball History by  Michael Salfino and Neil Paine](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-most-consistent-hitter-in-baseball-history/)

So I don't think there is another player with 4 or 3 years aside from the listed here (Khris Davis & Mookie Wilson) with the same batting average.

Comment: Khris Davis avg was NOT .248 in 2018. It was .2465 = 142/576